# Confusion with Trace and Dirac (Bra-Ket) notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, operator-theory, trace, quantum-mechanics

I'm am confused with the following:

> Let $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ be two qubit state vectors, with Bloch vectors $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{m}$ , respectively.
>   $$P_\psi = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\\ P_\phi = |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|
> $$
>   
> Then,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \text{Tr}(P_\psi P_\phi) &= \text{Tr}(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|) 
> \\&= \text{Tr}(\langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle) 
> \\&= | \langle\psi|\phi\rangle | ^2
> \end{align}
> $$

I do not understand how one get's $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ from $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$. It doesn't even seem to make sense to me since $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ is a scalar and $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$ an operator.

Also, does it make sense to take the trace of a scalar? Is the trace of a scalar the scalar itself? If so, I understand that we would have
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}(\langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle) &= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle 
\\&= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle (\langle\psi|\phi\rangle)^*
\\&= | \langle\psi|\phi\rangle | ^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

$\langle\psi |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ is a 1x1 matrix (scalar) and the trace of a 1x1 matrix is the scalar itself. Therefore,

$$
\text{Tr}(\langle\psi |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\psi\rangle) = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle
$$

Or, in english, the trace of a scalar is the scalar itself!

---

It has nothing to do with the fact that 
$$
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\phi\rangle\langle\phi| \neq \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle
$$
It is, instead, to do with 
$$
\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)
$$
(If A is an $m × n$ matrix and B an $n × m$ matrix)

Then, there is nothing wrong with:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|) &= \text{Tr}(\langle\psi |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\psi\rangle)
\\&= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle
\\&= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \overline{\langle\psi|\phi\rangle}
\\&= | \langle\psi|\phi\rangle | ^2
\end{align}
$$

---

### Original Answer

Here is my proposed answer:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}(P_\psi P_\phi) &= \text{Tr}(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|) 
\\&= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \text{Tr}(|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)
\\&= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle
\\&= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \overline{\langle\psi|\phi\rangle}
\\&= | \langle\psi|\phi\rangle | ^2
\end{align}
$$
, which coincides with the original answer. <s>Nevertheless, I still think that the method ilustrated in the question is wrong. Meaning that:
$
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\phi\rangle\langle\phi| \neq \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle
$
, where the LHS is an operator and the RHS a scalar.</s>

---

By the way,
$$
\text{Tr}(|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|) = \langle\phi|\psi\rangle
$$
comes from
$$
\langle\phi|\psi\rangle = \sum_n \langle\phi|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle
$$

Comment: My understanding is that bra-ket notation is designed with the express purpose of making sense of manipulations like $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi||\phi\rangle\langle\phi| = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle\langle\phi|$. And for the third line, we can utilize the formula $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ which holds for any two matrices $A$, $B$ for which both $AB$ and $BA$ are well-defined. (This also holds for 'infinite matrices' under suitable conditions.) That said, the computation can be justified.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you! I've updated my answer accordingly. I got stuck in thinking that $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\phi\rangle\langle\phi| = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ could not be a thing. The fact that $\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)$ makes all the difference here.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: @T.P.Vasconcelos Actually, $\mathrm{Tr} \big( \vert \phi \rangle \langle \phi \vert \vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi \vert \big) = \mathrm{Tr} \big( \langle \psi \vert \phi \rangle \langle \phi \vert \psi \rangle \big)$ **is** wrong. The reason being that $\langle \psi \vert \phi \rangle \langle \phi \vert \psi \rangle$ is a scalar and taking the trace of a scalar is not defined. Your first proposed answer was the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Diracules I am still not convinced by this. But I would argue that the scalar $\langle\psi |\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ is infact an element of the inner product space where $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ are defined. This would formally be a 1x1 matrix, where the definition of trace still applies.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert{#1}\rangle} \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle{#1}\rvert} \newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle{#1}|{#2}\rangle} \DeclareMathOperator{tr}{tr}$Yes, the trace of a scalar is the scalar itself, but $P_\psi P_\phi$ is not a scalar.
You have
\begin{equation*}
\tr(\ket{\psi}\bra{\psi}\ket{\phi}\bra{\phi})=
\tr(\ket{\psi}\braket{\psi}{\phi}\bra{\phi})=
\braket{\psi}{\phi}\tr(\ket{\psi}\bra{\phi}),
\end{equation*}
and I think that in the proof you provided they switched the positions of the bra and the ket within the trace, which is incorrect (they are not operators by themselves, and you cannot separate them).
You can choose a basis for your Hilbert space that includes $\ket{\psi}$, $\ket{\phi}$ and some other vectors $\ket{i}$: then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\tr(\ket{\psi}\bra{\phi})&=
\braket{\psi}{\psi}\braket{\phi}{\psi}+
\braket{\phi}{\psi}\braket{\phi}{\phi}+
\sum_i\braket{i}{\psi}\braket{\phi}{i}=\\&=
\braket{\phi}{\psi}+
\braket{\phi}{\psi}+
\sum_i\braket{i}{\psi}\braket{\phi}{i}=\\&=
2\braket{\phi}{\psi}+
\sum_i\braket{i}{\psi}\braket{\phi}{i},
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
assuming that $\ket{\phi}$ and $\ket{\psi}$ are normalised to 1.
Now, the trace is independent of the basis, so we can choose the $\ket{i}$ as we see fit: if we take them all orthogonal to the subspace spanned by $\ket{\phi}$ and $\ket{\psi}$, the previous expression reduces to
\begin{equation*}
\tr(\ket{\psi}\bra{\phi})=2\braket{\phi}{\psi}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore
\begin{equation*}
\tr(\ket{\psi}\bra{\psi}\ket{\phi}\bra{\phi})=
\braket{\psi}{\phi}\cdot 2\braket{\phi}{\psi}=
2\lvert\braket{\psi}{\phi}\rvert^2.
\end{equation*}

Comment: When computing the trace of $|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|$, it seems to me that you are making an extra assumption that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are orthogonal. If this is the case, we also have $\langle \psi | \phi \rangle = \langle \phi | \psi \rangle = 0$ and the result coincides with the proposed answer.

Comment: No, you cannot necessarily make an orthonormal basis out of $\phi$ and $\psi$. Pick one or the other (not both). Say $\psi$, and build a basis out of that vector. All of the other terms in the sum vanish, because the other vectors are orthogonal to psi. Your answer is off by a factor of 2, and that 2 will go away when you fix it.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer I didn't say that the whole basis is orthonormal, just that every element other than $\lvert\phi\rangle$ and $\lvert\psi\rangle$ is orthogonal to them.

Comment: @SangchulLee Could you please point me to where I made that assumption? Maybe I did so inadvertently...

Comment: @SangchulLee I have posted an answer to my own question. Would you like / mind to check if the reasoning is correct? Thank you!

Comment: I think you are referring to the formula $$ \operatorname{tr}(A) = \sum_k \langle \varphi_k, A\varphi_k \rangle $$ which is true when $\{\varphi_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis. But this is not guaranteed to hold for general basis $\{\varphi_k\}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Ah, I got carried away by the fact that trace is independent of the basis and went too far with that formula. Of course you're right!

Comment: @yellowquark Now that things are cleared up for you, can you fix your answer? Sorry if my earlier comment confused you.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's best if I delete it altogether...